# Смена mime типа картинки перед сохранением на сервере

Tags: php, изображения

Есть код:

```
//Получаем изображение с формы
$image = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
// Конвертируем в base64
$imageData = base64_encode(file_get_contents($image));
//Задаем ему mime тип gif
header('Content-Type: image/gif');
//Декодируем обратно в картинку
$image = base64_decode($imageData);
//Сохраняем на сервере
$res = file_put_contents(ROOT_DIR . "/uploads/fotos/" . $row['user_id'] . ".gif", $image);
```

Проблема в том что он в этом месте header('Content-Type: image/gif'); выводит картинку в браузер. Как мне менять mime тип не выводя результата в браузер. Конечная цель сохранять все картинки на сервере в формате и типе gif.

Comment: `header('Content-Type: image/gif');` - это вы не задаете mime-тип для картинки, а говорите браузеру, что сейчас вы будете показывать картинку. Соответственно, все ваши `base64_encode/base64_decode` бессмысленны, для этого нужны другие инструменты, например, [imagegif](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagegif.php)

Comment: Боюсь, вы не понимаете, что такое mime-тип. Это не какая-то абстрактная строка, а указание на то, какие данные содержит документ. Другими словами, пока вы работаете с image/gif, вы не можете сменить ему mime-тип - он всегда будет image/gif